# Firebase : Invalid Refresh Token while adding data to firebase emulator

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

I am getting the below error message while trying to write data to firestore emulator.

```
Failed to get token: com.google.firebase.FirebaseException: An internal error has occurred. [ INVALID_REFRESH_TOKEN ].

stream closed with status: status{code=unauthenticated, description=null, cause=com.google.firebase.firebaseexception: an internal error has occurred. [ invalid_refresh_token ]
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to call useEmulator on the [Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/emulator-suite/connect_firestore#android_ios_and_web_sdks) instance as well.

```
FirebaseFirestore firestore =  FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
firestore.useEmulator("localhost", 8080);
```